# jQuery show/hide only child within a dynamic list

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-selectors

Any idea how I can show/hide only the child '.link', from each list item, when the relevant input field is focused/blurred.

Something like the following, but I'm unsure how to apply (this) to it?

```
$('.input').focus(function () {
  $('li').next('.link').show();
});

$('.input').blur(function () {
  $('li').next('.link').hide();
});
```

Markup:

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <input class="input" value="1">
   </li>

   <li">   
     <a class="link" href="#"></a>         
   </li>
 </ul>

 <ul>
   <li>
     <input class="input" value="2">
   </li>

   <li>   
     <a class="link" href="#"></a>         
   </li>
 </ul>
etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes the structure of your markup is not going to change. You can use `.parent()` to get the parent element, `.next()` to get the following sibling, and `.children()` to get a child element. You can combine both event handlers into one, and improve efficiency by delegating the event handler higher up the DOM tree:

```
$("ul").on("focus blur", ".input", function (e) {
    var method = e.type === "focusin" ? "show" : "hide";
    $(this).parent().next().children(".link")[method]();
});
```

Note that the event type check is looking for `focusin` - jQuery appears to actually bind to `focusin` and `focusout` rather than `focus` and `blur`.

Answer (score 1):

If your structure is definitely as above, then you can simply use parent and next...

```
$('.input').focus(function () {
    $(this).parent().next().find(".link").show();
});

$('.input').blur(function () {
    $(this).parent().next().find(".link").hide();
});
```

Comment: Firstly, I fixed my schoolboy error (I had show instead of hide!), and fixed a couple of errors you had with jsFiddle (it wasn't the same code - no parent selector - and you had it on mootools, not jQuery), and here's the working version... http://jsfiddle.net/ZK877/1/